# Choice for NoSql database: flexible scheme, read performance

Tags: mongodb, cassandra, couchdb, ravendb

We are developing an application that will store approximately 5 TB of data.

Following criteria are important

- Flexible scheme
- Read performance
- Data scalability
- Maturity

There will not be a huge user load on the db, total userbase of approx 1000 user and 50 concurrent.

Raw data from scanning consoles will be added and used for analysis. This data structure may vary in time as new measurement metrics can be added.

The main table that will be queried and will contain the bulk of the data will consist of following columns

- CustomerId
- ConsoleId
- RunId
- ConsoleTypeId
- Timestamp
- multiple measurement columns

Queries will not be very complex and required retrieved by CustomerId, ConsoleId, RunId, ConsoleTypeId.

The retrieved data will then be passed and analyzed by `TIBCO SpotFire`

We are considering following databases

- RavenDb
- MongoDb
- CouchDb
- Cassandra

They all seem to fit the requirement. Perhaps Cassandra is not as flexible since the columns have to be defined and you cannot store entities with different columns/properties in the same table.

What would be the best option in this scenario?

Comment: Honestly, without knowing the use cases, nobody can actually give a proper answer. A list of requirements doesn't help here. So what are you going to do with those 5TB? What will the average size of an item be? In other words: "da beef, plz"! ;)

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg added data and query info

Comment: For the close vote: please comment why u want to close then i'll improve my question first. I'm trying to provide a specific scenario to make a NoSql choice.

Comment: Please take the [introductory tour](http://www.stackoverflow.com/tour). You might want to read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), which enhances the probability for getting a useful answer _drastically_. You might find [ESR](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_S._Raymond)'s excellent essay [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) helpful, too. In your special case,Mai have already stated what's needed... ;)